# CSS not working for html elements created in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Have a script that has html content in it. This script comes from an external website, it contains html content that is dynamic, as it get populated by rss feeds. this is the script. http://feed.informer.com/widgets/J9HBCBNMTQ.js

to view the contents, put this link into your browser, its exactly the same content

http://feed.informer.com/widgets/J9HBCBNMTQ.html

HOW THE SCRIPT WORKS

In order to display the html content in the front end, you have to wrap the script tag around html tags, like this for example.

```
<div>http://feed.informer.com/widgets/J9HBCBNMTQ.js</div>
```

ISSUE

Because i want to keep my html page free of hundreds of scripts, instead of having it in the html file, i wanted to put it in a js file which will be linked to the html file. Essentially use javascript to inject the script already wrapped in a body tag, creating a page WITHOUT me having to create extra html files.

WHAT I NEEDED IN SUMMERY

1) Have Javascript inject the script into the DOM already wrapped in or a body tag (or any html tag)

2) have javascript create pages on clicking a button or element, for different scripts i will be using instead of create a lot of html files

as you can see below. I use javascript to return the script already wrapped in the body with class .heraldone when the input button is clicked

```
  function page1() {
   return '<html><body class="heraldone"><script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://feed.informer.com/widgets/J9HBCBNMTQ.js"></script></body>        
</html>';
}

function page2() {
return '<html><body>Hello world (2)</body></html>';
}


function nextpage(page) {
if (!document.image) {
location.replace('javascript:page' + page + '()');
}
else {
location.href = 'javascript:page' + page + '()';
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Next page 1" onClick="nextpage(1)">
<input type="button" value="Next page 2" onClick="nextpage(2)">
```

ALL THIS WORKED WITH THE ABOVE CODE HOWEVER

Within this script tag are 5 divs designated #text1, #text2, #text3, #text4, #text5.

THESE DIVS ARE NOT IN THE ABOVE CODE, THEY ARE PART OF THE CONTENT WITHIN THE SCRIPT TAG.

Im trying to hide Four of these divs using css when the contents of the script are rendered in the from view. for example:

```
.heraldone #text2 {
display: none;
}

.heraldone #text3 {
display: none;
}

.heraldone #text4 {
display: none;
}

.heraldone #text5 {
display: none;
}
```

But my css is not working. It works well when i do it within the dev tools inspect element, but when i link a stylesheet with that css, its not working, even having the css on the same html page is not working. Instead of hiding the four elements and only showing one, it shows all of the, when i inspect the css in dev tools, there is no css code at all, like its not being picked up Any thoughts?

I STRESS THAT THE #text1, #text2 etc DIVS ARE NOT IN THE ABOVE CODE, THEY ARE PART OF THE HTML CONTENT WITHIN THE SCRIPT TAG.

Comment: This is very confusing, the CSS doesn't seem to match anything in the HTML, or javascript ?

Comment: .heraldone is this.  body class="heraldone">
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://feed.informer.com/widgets/J9HBCBNMTQ.js"></script></body>, the #text1, #text2, #text3, #text4, #text5. are divs WITHIN the script tag, this script tag has html contents from an external source @adeneo

Comment: i don't see your css being loaded into the page1 method, and I am baffled that this could even work. Wouldn't this just blank the whole page on click and try to then run a method that doesn't exist?

Comment: @Scottux it works, only the css doesn't work

Comment: post the html contents of one of these files that are loaded and the html of your page _after_ loading

Comment: @Johannes copy this into your browser, its the <no script> version, its exactly the same information that i'm loading. http://feed.informer.com/widgets/J9HBCBNMTQ.html

Comment: Make a jsFiddle or a CodePen of what exactly is giving you a hard time. We will also get a better view of what is really working and what not.

Comment: and where is the css you posted at the top of your post?

Comment: .heraldone is the body created in my javascript. the #text1 etc are styles inside the contents of the script tag feed.informer.com/widgets/J9HBCBNMTQ.js @Johannes

Comment: @GeorgiaB i can't use js fiddle or codepen because they don't allow html elements in the js windows, i don't know why.

Comment: @Drakata please read my answer below

Comment: @adeneo is that better?

Comment: @TylerH is that better?

Comment: @Patrick Kostjens is that clearer?

Comment: @Unheilig is that better?

Comment: @Alastair McCormack is that better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't even believe`location.replace('javascript:page' + page + '()')` works, but I simply moved the css into the returned html and images were hidden.

```
function page1() {
    return "<html><head><style>.heraldone #text2,.heraldone #text3,.heraldone #text4,.heraldone #text5 {display: none;}</style></head><body class='heraldone'><script src='http://feed.informer.com/widgets/J9HBCBNMTQ.js'><\/script><\/body><\/html>";
}

function page2() {
    return '<html><body>Hello world (2)</body></html>';
}

function nextpage(page) {
    if (!document.image) {
        location.replace('javascript:page' + page + '()');
    } else {
        location.href = 'javascript:page' + page + '()';
    }
}
```

Not sure what you are up to, but I would have chosen to replace out the body content of the main html page, rather than whatever dark magic is allowing this to even work as intended. This would have the benefit of keeping the returned page html to be smaller, and easier to follow. Something like `var pages = ['<script ... />','Hello world']; document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = pages[page-1];`

Comment: Thats it! @Scottux thats exactly what i needed! Now its working perfectly. thank you very much.

Comment: That's a rather nasty way to do it, but if using in-line style works chances are your problem is that some other CSS is being applied over your original method. (As in-line styles are top priority)

Comment: @DBS totally agreed. I added an alternative solution as well.

Comment: and this isn't in-line styles. it is an embedded stylesheet in an html page that is the result of a javascript function blowing away the original document. inline styles are like `<element style="display:none" />`

Comment: the main thing i wanted to do is load the script contents of http://feed.informer.com/widgets/J9HBCBNMTQ.js into the DOM through Javascript instead of putting it in a div with the html file, this was the only way i could make it work with my limited knowledge of javascript. @Scottux

Comment: I also wanted to to create dynamic pages of each individual #text1, #text2... using javascript but it was difficult. hence the black magic. @Scottux

Comment: I see, that script you are loading is using document.write() so you can't load it asynchronously. I suggest maybe breaking these into multiple html files (page1.html, page2.html) and using the nav buttons to replace an iframe's src maybe in an outer html file if you want to get more flexible with it later. Otherwise, if it works for you then who am I to judge, we all start somewhere man.

Answer (score 0):

Those styles that you listed at the top (#text2 - ...5) are *not* in that javascript. The only style in there that applies to any of those #text elements is

`#text3 {z-index: 2;position:absolute; margin-top: 50%;}`

So you'd have to include those styles in those referenced js files, I suppose, because they aren't anywhere.

Comment: they are in here, @Johanness.  feed.informer.com/widgets/J9HBCBNMTQ.js  as i keep saying.

Comment: I don't understand why this post keeps being voted down when the code works and the answer works, whats the problem people?

Comment: open that file and use the find function for "#text", which should find all these styles. the only thing you'll find is the `#text3`rule I quoted above